# System.* namespace collide with custom namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with a custom namespace that collide with the namespace System.*

## Setup

I have a custom library with the namespace **Powerdoo.System** it hold multiple tools and Extension of mine.

I have a Application that reference my custom tool library and includes a Entity Framework model. The namespace of the application is **Powerdoo.Model.MSSQL**.

## Problem

My custom namespace collides with the .Net default namespace **System.***.

Like here the "using System" is interpreted as "using Powerdoo.System":

[image]

## Question

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this problem **without rename** my tool library namespace or my application namespace.

### Update 1

Here is the reference tree of the application:

[image]

### Update 2

If I use *rigth-click > auto name space* the reference **using global::System.Data.Entity;** is added.

[image]

How can I bring Entity Framework to use *global::* usings on auto generated classes?

Comment: Did you try to put your "using System" before the "namespace Powerdoo.... "?

Comment: Yes that will work. But this is auto generated code from EF and so it get overwritten. :(

Comment: Microsoft reserved the word "System" for their own use.  Not something they enforce, just something they recommend in their [framework design guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Ignoring it is fine, dealing with the consequences is your burden.

Comment: No you misunderstood the guideline, "System.*" is forbidden, not "Somethink.Other.My.Custom.System".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "global::System" for the .net System namespace.
For your case, you have to alter the EF template.

Comment: Ok found it and fixed it. :)